# How to sort table values in ascending and descending with name value without using sort() function in PHP or ORDER BY in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I use the following code to get my resulted table, and I need to sort this table based on Clicking 'ascending' or 'descending' button respectively with my Name Value.
How can I make a custom `php` function for this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$sql_sel = "select * from contact";
$res_sel = mysql_query($sql_sel);
?>
<table><tr><td>Name </td><td>Email </td><td> Mobile</td><td>Web </td></tr>
<tr>
<?php
    while($row_sel = myqsl_fetch_array($res_sel)){
        $name = $row_sel['name'];
        $email = $row_sel['email'];
        $mobile $row_sel['mobile'];
        $web =$row_sel['web'];
        echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$mobile."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$web."</td></tr>";

    }
?>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Ascending" onclick="ascending()">
<input type="button" value="Descending" onclick="descending()">
```

Where I getting table with values from database table as in the order of execution.
My page having two buttons Ascending and Descending, while clicking on that, it results table values arranging in Ascending and Descending order based on name value. What should i code in 'ascending()' and 'descending()' to achieve this?i need this as a custom php function??

Comment: "without using inbuilt `sort` function in PHP or `order by` in SQL" Why don't you want to use those?

Comment: Use the javascript table sort plugin of your choice.

Comment: jQuery has a table sorter plugin - I should think there are several, both for JS libraries and standalone too.

Comment: (Don't forget to use the editor preview pane to ensure your question appears correctly. Some of your HTML was incorrectly formatted, and I had to fix that).

Comment: hello there this is one of the interview question i had got and i cant answer this . so please help me..i missed those lines thank you @halfer

Comment: use the jQuery datatable plugin all you have to do is in javascript add $('#table_id').datatable(); ... make the title td's of your table th and ur set

Comment: @JohnRuddell i need  a custom php function.

Comment: @AjeshVC If you want to do that in PHP, then you should of course modify your SQL to do the sorting.

Comment: @AjeshVC you cant sort your table  in php without re-doing your query with a different order by.. so the ascending() function would have to make another ajax request with a sort method of asc or desc for descending()

Comment: So you have explicit instructions to do this without using `ORDER BY` or any in-built sort functions? And the sorting cannot be done client-side?

Comment: If you can't use build in PHP or SQL order by why dont you sort them yourself? Something like creating another array containing all the values sorted with a loop inside a loop?

Comment: @JohnRuddell this is what i did today. but they are expecting any other solutions. becoz the question specifies you can't use php or sql in built functions to sort, use your own custom function.

Comment: @VMai if its an interview question for a job I doubt the OP gonna be able add a plugin, the OP is gonna need to create something to prove how much he knows but if he needed to post this here I guess he wont be getting the job...

Comment: Ok so if you can't do anything like that.. then you need to populate an array with everything sorted... then hit the same file when you click the button, resort accordingly and echo that table

Comment: @AjeshVC Please edit your question and include the requirements right at the start to clarify the specifications.

Comment: The question is most likely just a test of how well you can implement one of various [sorting algorithms](http://phpcoderblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/php-some-sorting-algorithms-bubble-sort-selection-sort-counting-sort-quicksort-shellsort-heapsort/) and whether or not you pick the most appropriate one.

Comment: @PatrickQ thats the most appropriate comment i've seen in a VERY long time.

Comment: What would be really interesting is if the company monitors Stack Overflow and saw the post

Comment: Yup. Although if I were doing the hiring, I don't think I'd automatically reject the candidate for asking. An answer such as "I did not know the answer off the top of my head, but after some research I came up with this..." could still be a good answer to me, assuming the solution was actually correct. But I digress :)

Comment: @PatrickQ man i done this with ajax function call, from where use sql ASC and DESC query to sort and return

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are passing a value called "sort".  It can be "dsc" for descending, and anything else (or not specified) for ascending.

First, start with parsing the value:

```
$sortMode = 'ASC';
if (array_key_exists('sort', $_REQUEST)) {
    if ($_REQUEST['sort'] == 'dsc') {
        $sortMode = 'DESC'
    }
}
```

Later on, when you create your query:

```
$sql_sel = "select * from contact order by name $sortMode";
```

This will cause the database to sort in the correct direction.

One important thing to note is that you should **never ever ever** pass user input (e.g. $_GET, $_POST, etc) directly into your SQL string so that you don't expose yourself to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Note that here we test the $_REQUEST parameter and set the actual PHP variable manually to avoid this.

In production applications, you should use [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) as much as possible (not relevant here since ASC/DESC is part of a statement, not a parameter).

Comment: Note that the question says "without using ... ORDER BY in SQL"

Comment: @PatrickQ note the OP also wants to magically order this in php instead of using javascript on the client-side for the table.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I know. That's why I asked for clarification. If there are restrictions in place, then an answer that violates those restrictions really isn't much use.